# Set the text of a View in android?

Tags: android, view, textview

I want to set text  against the view "text"....but settext is not available from here any sujjestion please ....????

```
   ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MembersdealStream_Modified.this,
                        R.layout.membersdeal_streampagepage_singlerow, R.id.tv_membersdeal_streampagepage_header, targetArray) {
                    @Override
                    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                        View row = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);


                        View text = row.findViewById(R.id.tv_membersdeal_streampagepage_description);
                        text.setTag(position); 


                        text.setOnClickListener(MembersdealStream_Modified.this);


                        return row;
                    }
                };
```

I wanna do something like

```
text.setText("Anything.....");`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `R.id.tv_membersdeal_streampagepage_description` is a `TextView`, then replace:

```
View text = row.findViewById(R.id.tv_membersdeal_streampagepage_description);
```

with:

```
TextView text = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.tv_membersdeal_streampagepage_description);
```

as `setText()` is a method on `TextView`, not on `View`.